# The strength of "There are no $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets"

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

For $\Gamma$ a set of second-order sentences in the empty language, say that a set $X$ is **$\Gamma$-pseudofinite** if $X$ is infinite but for every sentence $\varphi\in\Gamma$ which is satisfied in every finite pure set we have $X\models\varphi$. For example, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that the sentence "I can be linearly ordered, and every linear ordering of me is discrete" is true of exactly the finite sets, and so $\Sigma^1_1\wedge\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets do not exist; in the other direction, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that $\omega$ is $\Sigma^1_1$-pseudofinite.

The interesting case is $\Pi^1_1$. While $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that there are no $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets (consider "Every linear ordering of me is discrete"), [James Hanson showed in $\mathsf{ZF}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3767073/28111) that amorphous sets are $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite. My question is whether amorphousness is more-or-less the only way we get $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets:

> Over $\mathsf{ZF}$, does "There are no amorphous sets" imply "There are no $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets?"

Note that this is a bit weaker than asking whether every $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite set is amorphous. FWIW I think the answer to *that* question is negative (I suspect e.g. that the union of two $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets is $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite).

Comment: I wouldn't say that James *showed* that. It's a theorem of Agatha. James pointed it out.

Comment: Hunch: There's a permutation model due to [Howard & Yorke](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm133/fm133116.pdf) that might be interesting here. IIRC, take a model of ZFA+AC where the set of atoms $A$ is ordered isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. For $a_1 < \cdots < a_k$ let $F_{a_1,\ldots,a_k}$ be the group of permutations of $A$ that fix $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ and the intervals $(-\infty,a_1),(a_1,a_2),\ldots,(a_k,+\infty)$ (but aren't necessarily order-preserving). In the symmetric submodel, I don't think there are amorphous sets at all but $A$ is likely to be $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Ooh, that looks interesting! Neither piece is obvious to me, but they're both plausible. If that works out I wonder what "No $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite sets" would wind up meaning after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My "hunch" in the comments to the question appears to be correct! This model comes from *Howard, Paul E.; Yorke, Mary F.*, [**Definitions of finite**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-133-3-169-177), Fundam. Math. 133, No. 3, 169-177 (1989). [ZBL0704.03033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0704.03033). The paper has a few confusing typos and, in particular, the proof of Theorem~15 appears insufficient, so I'm sketching the argument in some detail, with another proof of that theorem.

---

$\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\fix}{\operatorname{fix}\nolimits}$Fix a ground model $\mathfrak{M}$ of ZFA+AC where the set $U$ of atoms is countably infinite and fix a dense linear ordering ${<}$ of $U$ without endpoints.
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the lattice of finite interval partitions of $U$, i.e., patitions of $U$ into finitely many blocks where each block is an interval of any shape.
This is a lattice under refinement $P \leq Q$ iff every block of $P$ is contained in a block of $Q$.
The meet $P \sqcap Q$ consists of all nonempty intersections of a block from $P$ and a block from $Q$.
The join $P \sqcup Q$ is more complicated: the blocks of $P \sqcup Q$ are maximal unions of the form $B_1\cup B_2 \cup \cdots \cup B_k$ where $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_k \in P \cup Q$ and $B_1 \cap B_2, B_2 \cap B_3, \ldots, B_{k-1} \cap B_k$ are all nonempty.
Given an interval partition $P$, we write ${\sim_P}$ for the associated equivalence relation: $x \sim_P y$ iff $x$ and $y$ belong to the same block of $P$.

Let $G$ be the group of permutations $\pi$ of $U$ with finite support $\supp\pi = \{ x \in U : \pi(x) \neq x \}$.
Given an interval partition $P$ of $U$, let $$G_P = \{ \pi \in G : (\forall B \in P)(\pi(B) = B) \}.$$
Note the following facts:

1. $G_{P \sqcap Q} = G_P \cap G_Q$.
2. If $\{x\}$ is a block of $P$ for each $x \in \supp\pi$ then $\pi G_P\pi^{-1} = G_P$.
3. $G_{P \sqcup Q}$ is the subgroup generated by $G_P \cup G_Q$.

It follows that these subgroups generate a normal filter $\mathcal{F}$ of subgroups of $G$.
Let $\mathfrak{N}$ be the symmetric submodel associated to $\mathcal{F}$:
$$\mathfrak{N} = \{ X \in \mathfrak{M} : \fix(X) \in \mathcal{F} \land X \subseteq \mathfrak{N} \}.$$
Note that by 3, for every $X \in \mathfrak{N}$ there is a coarsest interval partition $\supp(X)$ such that $G_P \subseteq \fix(X)$, namely $$\supp(X) = \bigsqcup \{ P : G_P \subseteq \operatorname{fix}(X) \}.$$

**Lemma.** For any set $X$ in $\mathfrak{N}$, if $\pi \in \fix(X)$ then for every $x_0 \in U$, $\pi(x_0)$ is not in a block of $\supp(X)$ which is adjacent to that of $x_0$.

*Proof.* Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $A,B$ are adjacent blocks of $\supp(X)$ and $x_0 \in A$, $\pi(x_0) \in B$ for some $x_0$.
We will show that for any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ the transposition $(a,b)$ fixes $X$. Note that at least one of $A$ or $B$ must be infinite. Let's assume that $B$ is infinite, the other case is symmetric.

1. Suppose $a = x_0$ and $b \notin \supp\pi$.
   Then $(a,b) = (x_0,b) = \pi^{-1}(\pi(x_0),b)\pi$.
2. Suppose $a = x_0$ and $b \in \supp\pi$.
   Then pick $b' \in B \setminus \supp\pi$ and note that $(a,b) = (a,b')(b,b')(a,b')$.
3. Suppose $a \neq x_0$.
   Then $(a,b) = (a,x_0)(x_0,b)(a,x_0)$

It follows that any permutation of $A \cup B$ fixes $X$, which contradicts the fact that $\supp(X)$ is the coarsest partition such that $G_{\supp(X)} \subseteq \fix(X)$.

**Claim 1 (Howard & Yorke, Theorem 15).** $\mathfrak{N}$ contains no amorphous sets.

*Proof.* Suppose $X \in \mathfrak{N}$ is infinite. If $G_{\supp(X)}$ fixes $X$ pointwise, then $X$ is wellorderable and therefore not amorphous.
Pick $x_0 \in X$ such that $P_0 = \supp(x_0)\sqcap\supp(X)$ properly refines $\supp(X)$.
Let $A,B$ be two adjacent blocks of $P_0$ which belong to the same block of $\supp(X)$.
Suppose $A$ has a right endpoint $a$; the case where $B$ has a left endpoint is symmetric.

Let $P_1$ be obtained from $P_0$ by replacing $A$ with $A\setminus\{a\}$ and $B$ with $B\cup\{a\}$.
Note that for $\phi,\psi \in G_{P_1}$, $\phi(x_0) = \psi(x_0) \iff \phi(a) = \psi(a)$.
Fix $b \in B$ such that $B\cap(-\infty,b)$ and $B\cap[b,+\infty)$ are both infinite.
Let
$$X_0 = \{ \pi(x_0) : \pi \in G_{P_1}, \pi(a) < b \}$$
and
$$X_1 = \{ \pi(x_0) : \pi \in G_{P_1}, \pi(a) \geq b \}.$$
These are two disjoint infinite subsets of $X$.
Moreover, $X_1, X_2 \in \mathfrak{N}$ since they are both fixed by $G_Q$ where $Q$ is a refinement of $P_0, P_1$, and $\{(-\infty,b),[b,+\infty)\}$.
Therefore $X$ is not amorphous.

**Claim 2.** $U$ is $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite in $\mathfrak{N}$.

*Sketch.*
Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $$(\forall Y \subseteq X^n, Z \subseteq X^m,\ldots )\phi(X,Y,Z,\ldots)$$ is a $\Pi^1_1$ statement which is true of every finite set $X$ but false for $X = U$.
Let $Y \subseteq U^n, Z \subseteq U^m,\ldots$ be sets in $\mathfrak{N}$ such that $\lnot\phi(U,Y,Z,\ldots)$.
Let $P = \supp(Y)\sqcap\supp(Z)\sqcap\cdots$

Note that there are only finitely many possibilities for $Y, Z, \ldots$
For example, when $n=1$ then $Y$ must be a union of some of the intervals from $P$.
When $n=2$, $Y$ must be a boolean combination of cartesian products of two intervals from $P$ and the diagonal set $\{(x,x) : x \in U\}$. And so on...

By an EF-style argument, if $V \subseteq U$ is a finite set such that that contains all the endpoints of intervals from $P$ each of the sets $P \cap B$ is sufficiently large when $B$ is an infinite interval from $P$, then $\phi(U,Y,Z,\ldots)$ is equivalent to $\phi(V, Y \cap V^n, Z \cap V^m,\ldots)$. It follows that $\lnot\phi(V, Y \cap V^n, Z \cap V^m, \ldots)$ for some finite set $V \subseteq U$, but this contradicts the assumption.

---

Since the ultimate goal is to obtain a more concrete understanding of what $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite means, I will propose an alternate conjecture.

Recall Tarski's notion of II-finite: *every chain of subsets of $X$ has a maximal element*. This is equivalent to the $\Pi^1_1$ statement: *every total preordering of $X$ has a maximal element*. So every $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite set is II-finite. It seems that the converse might be true but I will only propose the following:

**Conjecture.** There is no infinite $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite set if and only if there is no infinite II-finite set.

Comment: Your conjecture rubs me the wrong way. It sounds similar in spirit to saying that “total preorder without a maximal element” is a (in some sense) weakest axiom of infinity. (In model theory, an *axiom of infinity* is a FO sentence that has an infinite model, but no finite models.) It is well known that there is no weakest axiom of infinity up to interpretation. (Otherwise, we could decide validity in finite models: given a sentence $\phi$, exhaustively search for a finite countermodel to $\phi$, a proof of $\phi$, or a proof that $\phi$ interprets the purported weakest axiom of infinity.)

Comment: I'm having doubts about Claim 1 (Howard & Yorke Theorem 15). Their proof relies on the statement that if $\pi(x_0) = x_0$ then $\pi$ must also fix $\operatorname{supp}(x_0)$. This is false for $x_0 = [a,\infty)$ where $\operatorname{supp}(x_0) = \{a\}$ but, for example, if $a < b$ then the transposition of $a$ and $b$ fixes $x_0$. I'm not sure how to remedy this.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais That's an interesting issue, and I don't see how to resolve it either. Maybe ask a question about it? (I would, but I feel like I've asked/bumped enough questions recently.)

Comment: I am intrigued, but this will have to wait for tomorrow morning. (@Noah: Did I say that you're interfering with my other work yet? :-))

Comment: @Asaf and Noah, I think I fixed the Howard & Yorke proof. Do either of you want to double check?

Comment: @Emil This is very interesting. I'm now very curious about axioms of infinity. Is it known whether every axiom of infinity interprets an axiom of infinity where all relations have arity 2? (Or arity 3? etc.)

Comment: That should be the case, as every structure in a finite language is bi-interpretable with a graph, and by the same token, every sentence is bi-interpretable with a sentence in a language with a single binary predicate.

Comment: @Emil That's what I thought, but "finite" often leads to digging through footnotes. In any case, it seems plausible that the same kind of symmetric model could be made with the Rado graph on the set $U$ of atoms instead, which would seem to somehow refute your objection if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow. My objection is that a set is $\Pi^1_1$-pseudofinite iff it is an infinite set that doesn't carry a model of any axiom of infinity, thus your conjecture states that there is a particular axiom of infinity $A$ such that if every infinite set carries a model of *some* axiom of infinity, then every infinite set carries a model of $A$. This suggests that there exists a weakest axiom of infinity in some sense, namely $A$, while we know that under some reasonable  notions of comparison, no weakest axiom of infinity exists. Now, how does the random graph figure in this?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry for digging this back up from the graveyard... I was recently thinking about something related and I was wondering if you had found any issues with this answer other than the conjecture being probably wrong.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Sorry, I let this fall off my radar! I'm a bit pressed for time at the moment, but I'll take a look in the next couple days.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I just realized I never accepted this, my bad - thanks as always!